# /bin/bash: g++: command not found error 127

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, compiling, gcc

I was trying to install the software quicknet from a tar.gz file.
After running `./configure`, when I tried running `make`, it showed the following error:

```
g++ -I. -I.   -c QN_args.cc
/bin/bash: g++: command not found
make: *** [QN_args.o] Error 127
```

I have already installed the `gcc` compiler.

Answer (score 26):

You need the g++ compiler, not gcc, so install the `g++` package, and maybe `build-essential` for any needed headers:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

And if necessary (probably not for this package):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

You should read the README file(s), then the INSTALL file and follow the instructions.  They usually boil down to running configure:

```
./configure
```

Then running make:

```
make
```

Then, if you want to install the programs in a system area, run:

```
sudo make install
```

The configure step should search out the necessary parts (g++) and complain and stop if necessary parts are not found.  It builds the Makefile from the information about your system.

I had no issues with the downloaded package, but then again, I do have the `build-essential` package installed for what I do. `g++` gets installed into `/usr/bin`, which should be a normal part of your `PATH`.

Comment: i have installed g++ package but still it shows same problem.
if you want the link for the software i am trying to install then let me know
thank you

Comment: @JasmeenPatel ubfan1's instructions typically work for problems manifesting as you had described. So I think this question and answer are helping other people...but it's too bad this didn't enable you to fix your problem! You asked this over three years ago so my guess is that you either solved the problem or don't have quite the *same* problem compiling the software as you did back then. But if you are still looking for a solution to this same problem, then I definitely recommend that you edit your question with details on every step you took including where you obtained the .tar.gz file.